# Passing top-level mock function into jest.mock implementation

Tags: jestjs

I would like to test that a function being returned from a mocked function is called in a test in jest.

I have the following mock:

```js
const mockPromptAsync = jest.fn();

jest.mock("expo-auth-session/providers/facebook", () => ({
  useAuthRequest: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue([
      { foo: true },
      { type: "success", params: { access_token: "123" } },
      mockPromptAsync,
    ]),
}));
```

Where in my component I have:

```js
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
    responseType: ResponseType.Token,
    clientId: Constants.manifest.extra.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
  });
```

I want to test that the onPress here calls `mockPromptAsync`:

```
      <Button
        title="Login with Facebook"
        disabled={!request}
        onPress={() => {
          promptAsync();
        }}
      />
```

However, it seems like `mockPromptAsync` is undefined during the test:

```js
expect(mockPromptAsync).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

`promptAsync` is also undefined when I `console.log` in my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I went with was to define `jest.fn()` inline still, and perform the `expect` call be instantiating the mock:

```
import { useAuthRequest} from "expo-auth-session/providers/facebook";

...

expect(useAuthRequest()[2]).toBeCalledTimes(1)
```